# Error when trying to purge 100 messages or more

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've got a purge command on my Discord bot using Discord.js v12.2.0 and I keep getting an error but I can't figure out why. The error only occurs when I purge 100 messages or higher, anything lower then that works fine.

Here's is my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'purge',
    description: "Purge messages.",
    usage: '[amount]',
    aliases: ['prune'],
    execute(client, Discord, message, args, prefix, wrongchannelpublic, wrongchannelstaff, talkingserverbump, disabledcommand, nopermission, noarguments, colour, footer1, footer2) {
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === '703316042965057546')) { return message.delete({ timeout: 100 }), message.channel.send(nopermission).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 7000})) }
        if (!args[0] || isNaN(args[0])) { return message.delete({ timeout: 100 }), message.channel.send(noarguments).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 7000})) }
        if (args[0] < 1 || args[0] > 1000) { return message.delete({ timeout: 100 }), message.channel.send(`Please provide a number between 1 and 100, ${message.author}!`).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 7000})) }
        message.delete({ timeout: 100 })
        .then(() => {
            let remainder = args[0] % 100;
            let numOfTimes = (args[0]-remainder)/100;
            try {
                for (i = 0; i < numOfTimes; i++) {
                    message.channel.bulkDelete(100);
                }
                message.channel.bulkDelete(remainder);
            } catch (err) {
                const purgeerror = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                  .setDescription(`**Execution error**\nThe \`purge\` command ran by ${message.author} in ${message.channel} failed to execute.\nError: \`${err}\``)
                  .setColor('#ff0000')
                  .setTimestamp();
                message.channel.send(`<:cross:740242485728772137> Error: \`${err}\``);
                client.channels.cache.get('740251593382821920').send(purgeerror);
                console.log(`The purge command ran by ${message.author.tag} in #${message.channel.name} failed to execute. Error: ${err}`);
            }
        if (args[0] === "1") {
            setTimeout(()=>{ message.channel.send(`<:tick:740242485908996128> Purged ${args[0]} message.`).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 4000})) }, 1000)
        } else {
            setTimeout(()=>{ message.channel.send(`<:tick:740242485908996128> Purged ${args[0]} messages.`).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 4000})) }, 1000)
        }
        })
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
limit: int value should be greater than or equal to 1.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/root/o-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5) {
  name: 'DiscordAPIError',
  message: 'Invalid Form Body\nlimit: int value should be greater than or equal to 1.',
  method: 'get',
  path: '/channels/736996028787589201/messages?limit=0',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems some code you wrote created `path: '/channels/736996028787589201/messages?limit=0',` when it should be `path: '/channels/736996028787589201/messages?limit=1',` - running debug would show which - I would guess `message.channel.bulkDelete(remainder);` where remainder is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user supplies a multiple of 100 to delete, `remainder` will be zero, and `message.channel.bulkDelete(0)` throws an error because sending a request to do nothing is not valid.

Just add a conditional.

```
if(remainder > 0) message.channel.bulkDelete(remainder);
```

Comment: I believe I already posted that as a comment. Can't we just close this?

Comment: @mplungjan I was writing the answer as you edited your comment attributing it to the remainder. You're free to cast a close vote if you think the question should be closed, I just didn't think there was a good reason or duplicate to close it for.